# How to detect if a particular string is present at the start of a new line inside a textarea using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a text area where I need detect if '+' is followed by a space character at the start of each new line.I can get the keyCode on keyDown event,However this will return the keyCode even if the character is present in the middle of the string.I need to call a function only if the particular character combination is at the start of the new line in the text area.Could any one suggest me how to do this?

Comment: Post the code  like a [mcve]

Comment: Please share at least something that you have tried

Comment: what do you mean by "start of a new line"? text wraps, and where a new line starts depends on the amount of text and the width of the textarea, which can be changed by the user, depending on your styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to intercept when the user put the string `+` and `(space)` in a textarea and check in what position is it.

You could check the *previous characters* of last digited key, so:

- Listen on key down event
- Check if last key is `space` (because is the last char of the sequence you're looking for)
- Then check the previous characters, in your case a `newLine (\n)` followed by the string `"+ "`

```js
$("#test").keydown(function(e){
  if(e.key==' ')
    console.log(startsWith(e.target, '\n+'));
});

/*
  Returns true when:
  - text in 'target' starts with 'exp'
  - starting by current cursor position
*/
function startsWith(target, exp){
  var expLen = exp.length;
  var str = $(target).val();
  if(target.selectionStart > expLen){
    str = $(target).val();
  } else {
    if("\n" + $(target).val() == exp){
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  var start = target.selectionStart - expLen;
    
  var subStr = $(target).val().substr(start, expLen);
  if(subStr==exp) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
```

Note: 
I added following condition

```
if(target.selectionStart > expLen){
  str = $(target).val();
} else {
  if("\n" + $(target).val() == exp){
    return true;
  }
}
```

To find "+ " expression at the begin of the textarea's text.

I hope it helps you. Bye.